# OpenSeaDragon 2: Programmatic control over images' positions in colletions

Tags: ajax, silverlight, deepzoom, seadragon, openseadragon

I'm trying to move from Silverlight to OpenSeaDragon (PivotViewer), but so far I haven't been able to find out how to control programmatically position of every image in my image collection, so that it wouldn't be just a rectangular array of pictures. Maybe, sparseimage? Or maybe all it takes is to somehow add x and y coordinates to the collection's *cxml file?
Could you please point me to the right direction?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Which Seadragon are you using? https://github.com/seajax/seajax or https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/pull/446? If you're trying to do a Pivot viewer, the former has that functionality built in. The latter has multi-image now in that experimental branch, but no specific Pivot features.

Comment: @iangilman, thanks for your reply. I'm using github.com/seajax/seajax. I'm trying to work with Pivot Viewer because I thought this was the way to handle images separately, as a collection and not a single image. Basically, the task before me is a scalable canvas with Deep Zoom feature, and pictures with positions determined by my algorithm depending on user input and preferences. Have I been on the wrong track with the PivotViewer?

Comment: Well, I believe the Pivot Viewer feature of Seajax is just for creating the kind of grid you see at http://seajax.github.io/. I'm sure Seajax (without the Pivot Viewer feature) can support positioning images however you want, but I'm not familiar with that project. You might try filing an issue at https://github.com/seajax/seajax/issues. OpenSeadragon is also capable of image positioning, but it's still experimental, and doesn't directly support DZC.

Comment: @iangilman, thanks again for taking time to reply! You saved me lots of time and effort!

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working!